# Display two 1D and one 2D arrays in table form

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am Java learner and testing Java code and do not have much grip in Java at the moment.

At the moment what I want to achieve is that I have two 1D arrays of String and One 2D array of Integers. I want the results to be displayed in a table form but I am unable to do so. My code is below.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StudentResults {
    static String studentName;
    static String courseName;
    static int courseMarks;
    static String[] student = { "Jack Smith", "Jim Lucas", "Beck Barber",
            "Ann Walker", "Lucy Boxer" };

    static String[] course = { "Maths", "Business", "Java", "Design", "Project" };

    public static void studentMarks() {
        int[][] marks = { { 89, 70, 56, 87, 65 }, { 70, 65, 70, 83, 78 },
                { 60, 90, 63, 56, 79 }, { 74, 78, 45, 73, 85 },
                { 80, 90, 60, 70, 80 } };

        for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
            studentName = student[i];
            System.out.printf("\t\t" + studentName + "\t");

        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int j = 0; j < course.length; j++) {
            courseName = course[j];
            System.out.println(courseName + "\t");
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < marks.length; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < marks.length; n++) {
                courseMarks = marks[m][n];
                System.out.print("\t\t" + courseMarks + "\t\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        studentMarks();

    }
}
```

The output I am getting for the marks is in table but not inline with the course name. Just want to know if there is a way I can achieve this with the way I am working.

Cheers,

Comment: use System.out.print(courseName + "\t");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is some kind of homework (or self study) so l will give a hint rather than the full solution:

You want to print each subject, followed by each mark for that particurlar subject.
Currently, you are printing a list of all subjects, then you are printing the marks for each subject afterwards.

So this part of your code:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < course.length; j++) {
        courseName = course[j];
        System.out.println(courseName + "\t");
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < marks.length; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < marks.length; n++) {
            courseMarks = marks[m][n];
            System.out.print("\t\t" + courseMarks + "\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Should be a nested loop rather than two separate loops. ie, the second loop should be inside the first loop.

So you print one subject, then all the marks for that subject, then the next subject, then all the marks for that second subject and so on

There is still a bit of fiddling around before you will get the exact layout you want.But remember that `System.out.println()` will print the argument followed by a new line.

Comment: System.out.print(courseName + "\t"); will be a good way to display the records :)

Comment: Thanks cowls for the reply. I have tried to make it nested loop by bringing the } for j loop at the end after my m loop but it gives me a display like a new table for each row. (Which I do not want) I just want the results of 1st row to come up with Maths, 2nd row marks with Business and so on...

Comment: You can remove the outer for loop in the second loop: `for (int m = 0; m < marks.length; m++) {` and use the j loop variable instead of m. So only two for loops are necessary) Also as pointed out by @Mohit, avoid printing a new line directly after the coursename

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second for loop for printing the course and add the logic to print course in the third loop.

Code should look like this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StudentResults {
static String studentName;
static String courseName;
static int courseMarks;
static String[] student = { "Jack Smith", "Jim Lucas", "Beck Barber",
        "Ann Walker", "Lucy Boxer" };

static String[] course = { "Maths", "Business", "Java", "Design", "Project" };

public static void studentMarks() {
    int[][] marks = { { 89, 70, 56, 87, 65 }, { 70, 65, 70, 83, 78 },
            { 60, 90, 63, 56, 79 }, { 74, 78, 45, 73, 85 },
            { 80, 90, 60, 70, 80 } };

    for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
        studentName = student[i];
        System.out.printf("\t\t" + studentName + "\t");

    }
    System.out.println("");
    /*for (int j = 0; j < course.length; j++) {
        courseName = course[j];
        System.out.println(courseName + "\t");
    }*/
    for (int m = 0; m < marks.length; m++) {
         courseName = course[m];
         System.out.print(courseName + "\t\t");
        for (int n = 0; n < marks.length; n++) {
            courseMarks = marks[m][n];
            System.out.print("\t\t" + courseMarks + "\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    studentMarks();

}
```

}